# Update query in SQL, syntax error while running on java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, syntax

I'm trying to call the query:

```
UPDATE questions 
SET 1 = 4
WHERE questionid = 4;
```

But I keep receiving an SQL syntax error. I have a column in my table called '1', and I want to set that columns value to the integer 4. I tried some other queries(below), but I still the same error.

```
UPDATE questions 
SET '1' = 4
WHERE questionid = 4;

UPDATE questions 
SET '1' = 4
WHERE 'questionid' = 4;

UPDATE questions 
SET "1" = 4
WHERE questionid = 4;

UPDATE questions 
SET "1" = 4
WHERE "questionid" = 4;
```

I'm trying to perform this query in java using the executeUpdate() method from the Statement java API.

I know some of you would advise me using a PerformedStatement rather than a regular Statement for building queries, and I will do, once I can figure out why my query isn't accepting that 1 is a column name and not an integer.

Comment: Try square brackets around the column name, i.e. `SET [1] = 4`.  On a side note, why would you ever name your column that?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use backticks arround the column name:

```
UPDATE questions 
SET `1` = 4
WHERE questionid = 4;
```

Think about renaming your column.

Comment: ah I knew it was something really basic, thanks alot :D

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
UPDATE questions
SET [1] = 2 -- int
WHERE QuestionID = 1;
```